# Have nuclear reactors been used in space

Tags: power, nuclear

Have nuclear reactors ever been used in space as a way for power, instead of solar panels? If not, have any plans for one ever been made?

Comment: Does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_power_in_space answer your questions?

Comment: Ask the Canadians 'bout that. https://seanmunger.com/2016/01/24/the-nuke-that-fell-to-earth-the-terrifying-story-of-kosmos-954/